# JavaScript OO Programming and passing variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Using Joomla custom output module to display articles for a category, but have limited space.

Here is the test site: http://cshtest.camdendiocese.org/

In the footer you'll see the third of 4 columns has data.  It scrolls forward and backwards using JavaScript.  But as you see it has 4 columns, all of which work the same on different categories.

I'm having trouble with creating the other columns because they all will need to use separate data items, hence separate modules.  I was trying to create an object but got stopped specifying a JavaScript object inside PHP.

Here is the JavaScript that is working:

```
// This script provides forward and backward paging for article intros in footer-1
// create an array of strings
// Each array element is initalized at this time to establish global scope
var mytexts = []; 
mytexts[0] = "<h2>this is text string one</h2>";
mytexts[1] = "<h2>this is text string two</h2>";
mytexts[2] = "<h2>this is text string three</h2>";

// initialize variables
var txtNum = 0;
var txtLength = mytexts.length - 1;

// function to change string
function changeText(direction, col) {
// get next text number
txtNum = txtNum + direction;

// make sure we loop
if (txtNum > txtLength) {
    txtNum = 0;
    }
if (txtNum < 0) {
        txtNum = txtLength;
}
    // change the src attribute of the image
var colx = "col-" + col;
document.getElementById( colx ).innerHTML = mytexts[txtNum];

return false; // prevent default link
}
```

Here is the constructor I made to try to make an object:

```
function CatArticles(x0, x1, x2) {
    // This script provides forward and backward paging for article intros in footer-1
    // create an array of strings
    // Each array element is initalized at this time to establish global scope
    this.mytexts = []; 
    this.mytexts[0] = x0;
    this.mytexts[1] = x1;
    this.mytexts[2] = x2;

    // initialize variables
    this.Num = 0;
    this.txtLength = this.mytexts.length - 1;
    this.changeText = changeText;
}

// function to change string
function changeText (direction, col) {
    // get next text number
    this.Num = this.Num + direction;

    // make sure we loop
    if (this.Num > this.txtLength) {
        this.Num = 0;
        }
    if (this.Num < 0) {
            this.Num = this.txtLength;
    }
    // change the src attribute of the image
    var colx = "col-" + col;
    document.getElementById( colx ).innerHTML = this.mytexts[this.Num];

    return false; // prevent default link
}
```

I can instantiate the object with script tags in PHP but can't think how to get the variable created in the html to be output.   Do you have a suggestion or approach?

Comment: So, you're building an object with PHP, and you want your javascript to be able to access it? I generally recreate the object with a dynamically created inline `<script>` tag.

Comment: Or, wait, is that what you mean by "instantiate the object with script tags in PHP"? If that's not what you're asking, I have no idea what "the variable created in the html" means.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, considering they are two different scripts, server side and client side another, the solution would be to use ajax for interaction, after the page has already been generated by php.